# Где скачать языковые пакеты locale?

Tags: linux, zabbix, centos8

Доброго времени суток,

Нужно добавить новые языки на WEB Zabbix. Как подгрузить их к Заббиксу опыт есть, но задача следующая, машина не смотрит в мир, и я не могу найти соответсвующие locale. Может кто подскажет ссылочку на репозеторий, откуда их можна вытянуть?

Версия OS: CentOS 8

Заранее спасибо

Comment: если речь о glibc'шных локалях, то они обычно генерятся на конечной системе: добавляешь нужные в `/etc/locale.gen` и запускаешь `locale-gen`.